# jQuery BLUR - determine what the ID of the clicked item that triggered the blur is?

Tags: jquery

Given a live('blur', function(e) {} how can you get the attr('id') of the clicked item that triggered the blur?

Comment: When you say 'triggered the blur,' do you mean the element that's clicked *next* (to 'pull' focus from the previous element) or the element whose click-handler removes the blur from the element?

Comment: Did you receive a correct answer for this?  It appears that the item that was answered did not really answer the question as the ID that will be retrieved will be the id of the DOM element that lost the focus, not the item the focus was moved to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.live('blur', function(e) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
}
```

Comment: that will get id of the element which lost the focus